# 4 key shortcut does not work any more in GNOME Shell

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> (down/up) mapped to move window to next/previous workspace in Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 18.04 and until yesterday everything worked fine, but now the shortcut doesn't work any more. I checked in dconf, and the shortcut it is still there.

Every key still works on its own.

I tried to assign the shortcut to something else, but the Settings center doesn't intercept the shortcut when I try to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that for some reason with an update of the `keyboard-configuration` package (I suppose) for some reason the shortcut `alt+shift` was assigned to `Switching to another layout`.

I removed that with Gnome Tweaks:

- open Gnome Tweaks
- go to Keyboard & Mouse section
- click `Additional Layout Options`
- Remove the selection from `Switching to another layout`

Comment: How to "Remove the section from"?